# Powershell problem when changing channel from Stable to Master in Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, sdk

After changing the Flutter SDK channel from Stable to Master I now get this error when running Flutter commands:

```
Error: PowerShell executable not found.
       Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved my problem after installing Windows Management Framework 5.1

Link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54616.

Comment: mashullah ali jan so so nice answer

Comment: Not working. Framework is not suitable for my system.

Answer (score 11):

Add powershell.exe to your path in environment variables. You can find it under:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Comment: If this doesn't work: I was additionally required to add Flutter to the `path`.

Answer (score 5):

Go to System Properties -> Advanced System setting -> Environment Variable -> User variables - > Path

Add powershell.exe to your path in environment variables. You can find it here

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and was able to solve it as mentioned by @pallav-bohara and @ashirbad. But just wanted to add some complementary configurations you might need as well. Following procedure tested in Windows 10:

1. Add this to the User-level environment variable PATH, if you don't have:

> C:\Windows\System32

2. Add PowerShell path to User-level environment variable PATH, as Flutter tools depends on PowerShell 5.0 and above.
   But better place the paths of Step-1 & Step-2 before flutter or npm path:

> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Note: Of course, you should also ensure to have your flutter bin correctly set.

I actually found this solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15675#issuecomment-374139649) which saved some valuable time and wanted to summarize all the important points.